# How AWR report can help to find the root cause of slowness of application

Tags: database, oracle

While running a job in the application,it takes 9 hours to complete the job(Which is not expected). So how AWR report can help to find the cause of this slowness(delay). I am using Oracle Database.

Comment: useally i check this `SQL ordered by Elapsed Time (Global)` and i search f or the application i am using

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of information in an AWR report, and it's probably impossible to give a complete answer here. Also be wary of posting "snippets" of an AWR report (unless expressly ask for by someone), because all you are doing is "hiding" information.
Having said that, an AWR report is a useful tool for investigating system performance. If you have a particular (or a few) slow SQL statements, then the tool of choice is the SQL Monitor report.

Are you able to post the report?

Answer (score 0):

There is lot thing on AWR report which vary depend on sivation. There might be parameter.There is hard parsing happen on query need identity to app owner.Each parameter have different specification which came after experience is increase.

Wait Events Statistics Section: shows a breakdown of the main wait events in the database including foreground and background database wait events as well as time model, operating system, service, and wait classes statistics.

Wait Events: This AWR report section provides more detailed wait event information for foreground user processes which includes Top 5 wait events and many other wait events that occurred during the snapshot interval.

Background Wait Events: This section is relevant to the background process wait events.

Time Model Statistics: Time mode statistics report how database-processing time is spent. This section contains detailed timing information on particular components participating in database processing.